# Careers job ad for my company always showing

Tags: discussion, jobs, advertising

I keep getting a job offered by my company everywhere a careers ads box is shown. Is that a normal or intended behaviour?

Here's the company page, you can see that I'm already added to the company: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/pocket-playlab

And here's a screenshot taken from StackOverflow:

[image]

I think I shouldn't be receiving job offers from the company I work at, should I?

Answer (score 1):

This is purely because of 'location based targeting' which is used here (one of the many other factors) while serving the career ads. Currently, on [your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/159127/tamer-shlash) you have set 'Bangkok, Thailand' as your location. The company PlayLab Ltd. is also located in Bangkok, Thailand and currently has an active listing for [Software Engineer(Backend)](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=Playlab) position listed on SO Careers site. Hence the job ad from the PlayLab.

Yes, I agree with you and there should be a smart mechanism to stop displaying the job ads from the company you currently work for.